# add new user in lotus notes with java

Tags: java, lotus-notes

i want add a new user in lotus notes using java program but i am not aware of domino. I am trying to do this on my local so what all i need to download and how to do this I already have eclipse and lotus notes client on my system Please help me on this issue or any example codes of this.

Comment: Not aware of any code personally, but the Admin client does allow for adding mass users. The process to add a user is not trivial from a coding point of view.

Comment: u mean we can not do it from java program..??? if not how can we do it...

Comment: You can do it from within the Administrator client. Click the people tab, on the right is an option to Add users. The UI at that point will show you all the settings.

Comment: I stand corrected. See answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the "RegisterNewUser" method on the Registration class.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REGISTERNEWUSER_METHOD_JAVA.html

Should be what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, but i am not aware of how to start. i mean how to connect lotus notes with our eclipse project. can you please provide me brief introduction. thank you.

Comment: Notes Java API is a wrapper for DLL calls. So if you plan to use this with a notes client installed, then you need to use the Notes.JAR. If you plan to only use connecting to a domino server (No Notes installed) then use the NCSO.JAR. Check the following http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_9_CODING_GUIDELINES_JAVA.html

Answer (score 5):

So basically, you have two questions.

1) How can I write a Java Agent for Notes/Domino in Eclipse without using Domino Designer?

IBM provides a nice guide on how to set up Eclipse to create and debug a Domino Java Agent: "[Using Lotus Notes with Eclipse to manage and run your Java programs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-eclipse/)".
Via Google, I also found a nice tutorial by [Michel Van der Meiren](http://blog.lotusnotes.be/domino/archive/2007-12-08-eclipse-agents.html) and [Rishi](http://lotus-blogs.blogspot.com/2009/06/domino-java-development-using-eclipse.html).

2) How can I create a new Domino User inside a Java Agent?

As Simon already mentioned, there is the "[RegisterNewUser](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REGISTERNEWUSER_METHOD_JAVA.html)" method on the Registration class. As you would need the certifier files for that, it would be advisable that your Domino Admin first creates a "[Domino server-based certification authority](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_ABOUT_USING_SSL_TO_SECURE_AN_INTRANET_MIDTOPIC_407932275229448165.html)". Using that, you wouldn't need access to the certifier files in your Java app to create a new user.

Answer (score 0):

**This agent registers one example user.**

For further info: ([example link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLE_REGISTERNEWUSER_METHOD_JAVA.html?lang=es))

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.Vector;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
  public void NotesMain() {
    try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
      // (Your code goes here) 
      Registration reg = session.createRegistration();
      reg.setRegistrationServer("localhost"); //provide here your server name
      reg.setCreateMailDb(true);
      reg.setCertifierIDFile("c:\\NotesAdministrator\\cert.id");
      DateTime dt = session.createDateTime("Today");
      dt.setNow();
      dt.adjustYear(1);
      reg.setExpiration(dt);
      reg.setIDType(Registration.ID_HIERARCHICAL);
      reg.setNorthAmerican(false);
      reg.setMinPasswordLength(5); // password strength
      Vector orgs = new Vector();
      orgs.addElement("Japanese OU");
      orgs.addElement("PRC OU");
      orgs.addElement("Korean OU");
      reg.setAltOrgUnit(orgs);
      Vector langs = new Vector();
      langs.addElement("ja");
      langs.addElement("zh-CN");
      langs.addElement("ko");
      reg.setAltOrgUnitLang(langs);
      reg.setUpdateAddressBook(true);
      reg.setStoreIDInAddressBook(true);
      if (reg.registerNewUser("Taylor", // last name
        "c:\\NotesAdministrator\\mtaylor.id", // file to be created
        "CN=AceOne/O=AceHardware", // mail server
        "Mike", // first name
        "", // middle initial
        "AceHardware", // certifier password
        "", // location field
        "", // comment field
        "mail\\mtaylor.nsf", // mail file
        "", // forwarding domain
        "AceHardware", //user password
        "Japanese name for Mike", //alternate name
        "ja")) // alternate language
      {
        System.out.println("Registration succeeded"); 
      }
      else { 
        System.out.println("Registration failed"); 
      }

    } catch(NotesException e) {
      System.out.println(e.id + " " + e.text);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```